# Regex in Notepad++ 6

Tags: notepad++, regex

So, [Notepad++ got updated to v6.0](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html).  One of their new features is `PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions)`.

I tried to use this new feature to find and replace things in a file.  I tried the regular expression:

```
{\$([a-zA-Z_]*)}
```

and it yelled at me, saying "Invalid regular expression".

I tested this regex in other programs (like my main IDE, [Geany](http://www.geany.org/)), and it worked fine.

Why does this not work in Notepad++ 6.0?

Comment: What do you expect your regexp to do?

Comment: I'd expect it to match strings like this: `{$first_name}`, `{$street_address}`.  Which it does: http://rubular.com/r/uSup4HRn7n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the `{}` like so:

```
\{\$([a-zA-Z_]*)\}
```

I assume Geany and rubular.com don't use PCRE (or they use it differently). Please note that `{}` are usually used to denote quantifiers.

Without having checked the source, I can only assume that Notepad++ tries to be too smart before passing the regular expression to the PCRE library. If I run the following code in PHP:

```
echo preg_match( '{\$([a-zA-Z_]*)}', '{$something}' );
```

It prints `1` right away. No need to escape anything.

Sorry that I can't *explain* it :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused myself, to be honest.

Comment: In PHP, you need to escape the `$`, but not the `{}`.  http://ideone.com/oy44V

Comment: @Rocket I think you only need to escape `$` if you use double-quotes `"` instead of single-quotes `'`.

Comment: But, `$` means "end of string" in regex.  You'd need to escape it double quotes because of PHP's variable interpolation.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. You're obviously right. Thanks for noticing.